# How would I get this to produce random results instead of descending?

Tags: php, socialengine

I have tried changing it from DESC to RAND() and it doesn't work.
It lets me change it to ASC and that works fine.

```
    $select = $photosTbl->select()
        ->where('contest_id=?', $this->getIdentity())
        ->order('votes DESC');
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

->order('RAND()');

would likely do it. Not very nice to let the database do it

Comment: Thanks, it's only a very small table and I see no issue in speed. Thanks again!